# ROR- Syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I has been banging my head over the wall for sometimes now.  Don't know why I even get the syntax error on collection_select() when I am pretty sure it is correct.  Please help Rail 2.1.1.

```
<%= f.collection_select (:location_id, Location.find(:all), :id, :name, :prompt => true, 
        {:onchange => remote_function(
        :url => {:action => "loc_selected", :controller => "location", 
            :id=> location.id},
        :with => "'location_id='+this.value")}) %>
```

compile error

> c:/Users/Tau/rails_proj/incident/app/views/events/_general_step.html.erb:35: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting tASSOC
>   ..."'location_id='+this.value")}) ).to_s); _erbout.concat "\n  ...

Comment: Please format your code by indenting it 4 spaces. Also, are you using haml or erb?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing curly braces around `:prompt => true` . This argument to collection select needs to be a hash. Fix it by using `{:prompt => true}`.

And please, format your code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I am new to everything including ROR and this website.   Please forgive me for not formating my code.  I want to do this right the next time I post question on this website, so can you tell me what do you mean "format code"?